# Background acrylic background in javascript app

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp

Is it possible to create Windows 10 javascript app with transparent acrylic background like this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know right now, it's not possible to use Acrylic in a JavaScript based app.

If it was static content, you could maybe use a WebView in a C# app and then use a [WebViewBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewBrush) to layer with some sort of Acrylic effect, but for anything needing input, I don't think it would work too well.